# Why are my comments deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments

> Hello,
>
> Congratulations -- you are one of the top new English Language and
>   Usage - Stack Exchange users for the week of Aug 6 2012!
>
> http://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/english/2012-08-06
>
> It's users like you who make the English Language and Usage - Stack
>   Exchange community worth visiting in the first place. You can always
>   find your profile at:
>
> https://english.stackexchange.com/users/24531/xavier-vidal-hernandez
>
> Please don't hesitate to ...
>
> ```
> provide feedback on how we can improve on Meta English Language and Usage - Stack Exchange
>
> visit our real time web chat to meet fellow community members
>
> flag any comments or posts you feel should be followed up on by our community moderators
>
> email us directly at team+english@stackexchange.com any time
> ```
>
> Welcome, and thanks for being a part of our community!

I have received that mail from StackExchange, and I want to generate confidence acting in coherence with the values of the company stated there; but my comments are often deleted without any explanations and without to listen to any reason. So, I'm shocked to notice how much the thinking of the community (♦?) creeps into my own thinking and I do not know why!

**For people who do not know my activity**, the following is a list of my selected contributions, the others - even the deleted comments - are pretty similar in style:

> *But, generally speaking, problems are not rooted in misunderstandings
>   ('long ago' != 'a long time') by distorting or forgetting what words
>   actually mean in everyday use! Furthermore, as far as I concern, you
>   get into trouble by trying to understand words outside of the context
>   of their use in spoken language, as - precisely - the OP said! That
>   being said, I cannot vote up this answer!*

> *Finally an important question about the nature of our perception of shape properties has arrived! But, really, it would take time and
>   mental effort to figure these things out, and, however, there is no
>   reason to doubt about the reference you quoted!*

> *An excellent explanation, expressed in terms that can be understood
>   without the need of lots of philosophical knowledge, but I would
>   express my firmly conviction that 'dialectic' cannot be fully
>   comprehended without an understanding of death and, for this scope,
>   you should have posted another answer to avoid the death of the first
>   @Henrik Erlandsson's comment!*

What is wrong in my activity on this site?

Comment: Well let me be frank about *my* reasons. I deleted some of your comments because Sartre suggests the use of nationalism to read and modify language. Thus I am faced with a choice: either reject structuralist discourse or conclude that government is capable of significance. This subject is interpolated into a textual libertarianism that includes narrativity as a totality. Therefore, any number of dematerialisms concerning the paradigm, and some would say the dialectic, of subtextual class exist. Derrida uses the term ‘predialectic deconstruction’ to denote this, and other things.

Comment: My reasons are less philosophical. Many of your comments are inherently chatty, which means they become noise on a question or answer.

Comment: To me, your comments tend to be academic to the point of inscrutability. 'Dialectic'? 'Death'? There is so much thought and localized academic experience expected that it is very hard to understand, almost a mix of random erudite words. I don't think that is a reason for flagging or deletion, but others might. This is not an explanation but comments are considered expendable; an answer is supposed to stand without any of the following comments.

Comment: This is relatively minor compared to the other salient points, but it may be worth mentioning the overuse of exclamation marks.

Comment: What @Mitch said *("comments are considered expendable")*, and others imply. Like many, I get suckered into "chatty" comments now and then. I don't mind if mods remove them later, so long as I don't get moaned at too much for posting them in the first place. Even comments that lead to improved answers can reasonably be deleted after the improvements have been made. Comments *primarily* intended to turn ELU into a chat forum aren't really helpful.

Answer (score 17):

Looks like a typical signal transmission problem to me.

Put simply, the signal you emit seems to be cluttered with too much noise...
Below is a humouristic little chart, inspired by the OSI model, that will illustrate the idea.

To reach other EL&U readers, the waves originating from your cortex must follow a complex path and undergo a huge variety of transformations, of which I shamelessly represented only a few.
None of these transformations is 100% faithful of course.  It is therefore not impossible that some undesirable transcription errors could have mangled your comments.

[image]

To find out on which side of the double stack the errors are more likely to have happened I'd try to understand whether different receivers on the right hand side experienced the same garbled reception.  In which case you might want to fix the left hand side.
The good news is, that there is only one instance of this stack.

As you must have realised by now, a significant proportion of users familiar with this forum take an interest in one or more of these layers as well as in the whole transmission process.
So there is a lot of room for exchanging ideas. The title of this Q&A sites family says it all.

Bearing this in mind, I'm therefore convinced that once this temporary transmission problem is fixed, the communication between the EL&U community and yourself will be fruitful.

Till then, welcome to EL&U.

Comment: +1 for the Smurfs, and the most admirable diplomacy.

Comment: [Ranophage](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24735/) though you are, there is wisdom and wit in your words! I have my own ideas on what I might want to say to OP, obviously. So far, I endorse just about every comment and answer on this page - but in the true spirit of the *Entente Cordiale*, I acknowledge this as the *best* answer because [laughter is the **best** medicine](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-14889165).

Answer (score 15):

Thank you for your contributions to the site. I am glad that you wish to be a helpful contributor here. You are a very new user, and the fact that you are already a top contributor speaks to your efforts.

For that reason, I am glad that you chose to post your question here on the Meta site.  It gives us the opportunity to answer your concerns in a more detailed fashion than comments and also may help other new users in future.

Since you are new here, you might not know that moderators are not solely responsible for comment deletion.  If your comments have been flagged as "spam" or "offensive" by enough users, they will be deleted automatically by the system, and we mods might not even see those flags.

Other flags require some intercession on the part of the mod who reviews the flag.  Comments that are marked as "not constructive,"  "chatty," or that are "custom" with a message to a mod all need to be reviewed first.  In this case, comment deletion is at the discretion of the reviewing mod, although the more flags there are on a comment, the more likely it is to get deleted.

It is not within the scope of our duties to *always* leave a comment to explain why comments have been deleted. It rather defeats the purpose of comment deletion, and also it is quite time-consuming, as well you can imagine.  Oftentimes, pruning comment chains is just a routine task.

As for why specific comments of yours were deleted, reviewing the [guidelines](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) for posting comments may help you understand why some comments were flagged by the community.  If you have particular concerns or a question about why a particular comment was deleted, you can always ask on Meta (as you have done in this case).

Thank you again for your contributions.

Comment: I was going to answer but you gave a nice one. :) By the way, successful Spam/Offensive flagging brings an additional -100 reputation to the flagged user (for posts only). See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/176533).